# Is it possible to personalize the Media Library?

Tags: plugins, uploads, media-library

When we create a new post and click on Featured Image, I realize that WP creates a folder structure "year/month/image.jpg".

I'd like to change that behavior to "category_of_the_post/image.jpg" (or maybe "category_of_the_post/year/month/image.jpg").

The reason is that **I want to create a different album of each "category_of_the_post" folder**.

I tried different plugins, but **I didn't find any plugin which allow to upload the images at the same time we create the new post** (like when we upload the feature image). Maybe there is some other way to do the same stuff, but I'm beginning with this beautiful CMS so I cannot see the different possibilities from the top.

Comment: How should it work? I mean... What if you upload an image and then assign new category to this post? What if post is in multiple categories? What if given image is used in multiple posts?

Comment: Now, I understand why the images are ordered in that way, @KrzysiekDróżdż. I'd like the images where added to the first category selected by the user. Anyway, I understand it is not so easy to do!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-upload-dir/) might be a solution.

WordPress allow you to put uploads in year- and month-based folders. This plugin is somewhat smarter. You can construct paths from variables like post title, category, post author, post date and many more

But maybe you've already tried it